# How to access a photo that is upload into another project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have Solution named Company where I have three projects

> **Company**
>
> | ----**Company.Data**
>
> | ----**Company.Intranet**
>
> | ----**Company.Website**

In **Company.Intranet** project I upload photo into server (and save his name to database). It is possible get access to upload file from other project (eg. **Company.Website**)?

Answer (score -1):

Create a directory where you will store files (I create **wwwroot** dictionary, in this **images** dictionary and in this **item** dictionary)

> **Company
>
> | ----Company.Data
>
> | ----Company.Intranet
>
> | ----Company.Website
>
> | ----**wwwroot**
>
> |-------|--------**images**
>
> |-------|--------|--------**items**

In **Company.Intranet** edit **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
  {
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
   "..\\wwwroot\\images\\items")), 
   RequestPath = new PathString("/files"),
   EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false // you make this true or false.
   }
);
```

Where `"..\\wwwroot\\images\\items"` is path where your photo will be upload and `/files` is name 
is the name you will use when referring to photo.

In your controller change directory where you will be upload file

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Photo.FileName);
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..\\wwwroot\\images\\items", fileName);
    using (var fileSteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
      await Photo.CopyToAsync(fileSteam);
    }
```

Where `"..\\wwwroot\\images\\items"` is path where your photo will be upload -> the same one you provided in the **Startup.cs** file

---

In **Company.Website** edit **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
  {
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
   "..\\wwwroot\\images\\items")), 
   RequestPath = new PathString("/files"),
   EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false // you make this true or false.
   }
);
```

Where `"..\\wwwroot\\images\\items"` is path where your photo will be upload -> the same one you provided in the **Startup.cs** file in **Company.Intranet** project

To view pictures in View use code

```
<img src="@("/files/" + @item.Photo2)"/>
```

Where `/files/` is your custom name you will use when referring to photo and `@item.Photo2` is name your photo file (i storage it in database)

Comment: No, no, no. There is no guarantee that the projects will be deployed relative to each other like this, or even to the same server, just because they're part of the same solution.